# Showing the function $f$ is increasing.

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, proof-verification, continuity

Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is an increasing function and for any $y\in[f(a),f(b)],$ there exists a $\xi\in[a,b]$ such that $f(\xi)=y.$ Show that $f(.)$ is continuous on $[a,b]. $

Here is my argument, but I got stuck on the last part.

My goal is to show $$\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_0+\xi_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_0-\xi_n)=f(x_0),$$
where $\xi\downarrow0.$

As the sequence $f(x_0+\xi_n)$ is decreasing and bounded by $f(x_0),$ it converges. Similarly, the sequence $f(x_0-\xi_n)$ converges.  I want to show both of them converge to $f(x_0)$.

Suppose not, that is $U:=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_0+\xi_n)>f(x_0)$.

By our assumption, there must exist some $y>x_0$, such that $f(x_0)\leq f(y)<U$.  Fixed $\delta>0. $ As $y>x_0$, there exists some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|y-(x_0+\xi_n)|<\delta$ for all $n\geq k.$ Hence $f(y)\geq f(x_0+\xi_n)$ for all $n\geq k$. Which implies that $f(y)>U$. I want to make sure if my argument is correct and if there is any better solution for this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write that there exists $N$ such that $n>N$ implies that $x_0+\xi_n<y$, you deduce that $f(x+\xi_n)\leq f(y)$ and $lim_nf(x+\xi_n)\leq f(y)<U$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to prove this using an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument. Let $x\in [a, b]$ and $\epsilon > 0$ (without loss of generality, if $f(x)\neq f(a)$ and $f(x)\neq f(b)$, then let $\epsilon < \lvert f(x)-f(a)\rvert$ and $\epsilon < \lvert f(x)-f(b)\rvert$). Then, there are some $x_1, x_2\in [f(a), f(b)]$ such that $f(x_1) = f(x)-\epsilon$ and $f(x_2) = f(x)+\epsilon$. As $f$ is increasing, this implies that for $x'\in [x_1, x_2]$, $\lvert f(x)-f(x')\rvert\leq \epsilon$. Then, we just let $\delta\leq \min(x-x_1, x_2-x)$.